# Rest assured - how to pass token by headers and where did I wrong?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, rest-assured

I am able to log in a user and the response returns the token which I store in *token* variable then I try to pass the token that I received but the system returns 403 all the time. Where I got wrong or how it should look like?

```
@Test
    public void givenCorrectRoomDataWhenPostRoomThenReturnListWithNewlyCreatedRoomTest() {
        LoginEndpoint loginEndpoint = new LoginEndpoint();
        RoomPojo roomPojo = new RoomPojo();
        String token = loginEndpoint.createToken();

        roomPojo.setAccessible(true);
        roomPojo.setType("Single");
        roomPojo.setDescription("The very first single room");
        roomPojo.setImage("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/51/23/f0/5123f08b6e9c4441f27abf07cfee09c9.jpg");
        roomPojo.setRoomId(12);
        roomPojo.setRoomPrice(94);
        //roomPojo.setFeatures()
        roomPojo.setRoomNumber(22);

        given().header("Authorization", "Bearer" + token)
                .body(roomPojo)
                .when().post("room/")
                .then().statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

```
public class LoginEndpoint {

    public String createToken(){
        AuthPojo authPayload = new AuthPojo("admin", "password");

        return  given()
                .body(authPayload)
                .post("https://automationintesting.online/auth/login")
                .asString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure POST /room is supported ? I googled the URL and I see GET and POST /auth but not POST/room, Is this working on POSTMAN ?

Comment: Yes. Just log in to the website provided in logs(credentials: admin // password) and then you will be able to hit a POST method. I am curious how does the POST /room request should look like.

Answer (score 0):

the return statement in `createToken()` will return the complete response as string. You need only the token value, The below works

```
return RestAssured.given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(authPayload)
            .post("https://automationintesting.online/auth/login").jsonPath().getString("token");
```

Comment: Hi @Wilfred Clement and thank you for the answer. Despite I passed the token using header, still I have 403 response after hitting the endpoint. I have no idea what is wrong there

Comment: Add a `.log().all()` after the `given()` and `then()` and post the output here

Comment: I posted the output in a separate answer. Please look at it closer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how the test look like:

```
Starting test: givenCorrectRoomDataWhenPostRoomThenReturnListWithNewlyCreatedRoomTest

Request method: POST
Request URI:    https://automationintesting.online/auth/login
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=application/json
                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:
{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "password"
}
HTTP/1.1 200 
Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2020 21:02:33 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d66c0d43743f5ab6b507895c46a1759941597093353; expires=Wed, 09-Sep-20 21:02:33 GMT; path=/; domain=.automationintesting.online; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: 047bc7af4b0000f28820355200000001
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 5c0ca8921e37f288-WAW
Content-Encoding: gzip

{
    "token": "SJQFbE5AJ4Z2qAy9"
}
Request method: POST
Request URI:    https://automationintesting.online/room/
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=application/json
                Authorization=Bearer SJQFbE5AJ4Z2qAy9
                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:
{
    "accessible": true,
    "description": "The very first single room",
    "image": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/51/23/f0/5123f08b6e9c4441f27abf07cfee09c9.jpg",
    "roomNumber": 22,
    "roomPrice": 94,
    "roomId": 12,
    "type": "Single"
}
HTTP/1.1 403 
Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2020 21:02:34 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d9b3ecac04541248cba57b4c19565f97e1597093354; expires=Wed, 09-Sep-20 21:02:34 GMT; path=/; domain=.automationintesting.online; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: 047bc7b2bc0000ffb80329f200000001
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 5c0ca89798b1ffb8-WAW
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionUtils (file:/home/maryna/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/3.0.2/groovy-3.0.2.jar) to constructor java.lang.AssertionError(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Test: givenCorrectRoomDataWhenPostRoomThenReturnListWithNewlyCreatedRoomTest has failed.



java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <403>.


    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:277)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:493)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:674)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:193)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:126)
    at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$statusCode$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:134)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:89)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.super$2$statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy:142)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy)
    at tests.Tests.givenCorrectRoomDataWhenPostRoomThenReturnListWithNewlyCreatedRoomTest(Tests.java:93)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)

Finishing: bookingRestAssuredTesting
```